# C++ Compilation flags for an R package in Windows/Mac

Tags: c++11, rcpp, intel-mkl, compiler-flags, r-package

I developed an R package which calls C++ code through Rcpp and RcppEigen. My `Makevars.win` looks like this (the enumeration is meant to refer to my questions)

1. CXX_STD = CXX11
2. PKG_CPPFLAGS = -fopenmp -O3 -Wall -ftree-vectorize -march=native -mavx -mfma
3. PKG_CXXFLAGS += $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
4. PKG_LIBS = -fopenmp
5. PKG_LIBS += $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
6. PKG_CPPFLAGS += -I../inst/include/

as I want to use OpenMP and link the R package against Intel MKL library. I am also adding in my source files the plugins `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]` and `// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]`.

When I compile the package everything works fine but I am still getting the default compilation flags `-O2` and `-std=c++0x`. So my questions are:

A. isn't 1. supposed to force `-std=c++11` (by the way, using the same Makevars yields the right C++ version, so there must be something specific to Windows)?

B. does 3 repeats fopenmp in 2?

C. how to check whether 5. has been taken into account? I am asking this as the same package built on Mac is much faster than on Windows while their configurations are the same. I have done some benchmark of the same code on Windows using Microsoft R Open and Mac, and Windows was faster in that case.

Thank you very much for your very precious help.

Answer (score 3):

Where to start?

First off, compilation and linking options are based on the *union* of R's `Makeconf` and you package's `src/Makevars`.  You can add to value, you cannot replace.

Second, and related, which BLAS you get is a *system setup* issue. You cannot generally govern that from your package.

Third, plugins for `sourceCpp()` and `cppFunction()`. In packages you make direct declarations, ie `CXX_STD=CXX11`.

Fourth, there are almost 1000 packages on CRAN using Rcpp. Sometimes it helps just to look at what some of these do. Many employ OpenMP.

Fifth, OpenMP is severely challenging on OS X thanks to Apple. I've forgotten what the Windows situation is. It *just works* on Linux.

Comment: Just works on Windows... only macOS needs special treatment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, appreciate it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Sounds like I was unclear... I am stating that those flags are in my src/Makevars I used to build the R package and that CXX_STD=CXX11 is not taken into account on Windows, but it is on Mac. It is not clear to me why. Then, as it is obvious, I've looked at packages using OpenMP (which led to my 5.). Finally, I also thought that I was clear while saying that the package builds fine on Windows (using openmp). My questions are related to whether my flags are correct and not redundant, and why the std=c++11 and the -O3 are not taken into account in Windows (they are on Mac).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks your try anyway.

Comment: I found answers to the question on http://web.mit.edu/r_v3.3.1/R-exts.pdf

Comment: So ... what was the fix then?  (And that is just one of many URLs for the current manual.)